# UIScrollView duplicate information

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, duplication

I got an app with big `UIScrollView` as a root `viewController`.

This scrollView present some other views through `presentViewController` or `pushViewControler`, doesnt matter. But when i going back to `scrollView`, information, that was presented last time freeze, and i scroll duplicate inforamtion.

[image]

How can i clean `scrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

Clean scrollView

```
for([UIView * subview in [scrollView subviews])
{
 [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem.

My scroll drawing everytime when view appear.